# Is EF Core resistant to change the order of configurations in OnModelCreating?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let's assume, we have following model configuration and migrations already applied

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Property>()...
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>();
}
```

Does it any difference whether new entity configuration will be added at the beginning in the middle or at the end of current configurations? What's more, does it affect migrations when the order of configuration will be totally changed through refactoring?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>();
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>();
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Property>()...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For explicit fluent configurations the order doesn't matter, and the entity configurations will override any conventions.

But if you are adding custom conventions, the order can matter, as documented in the section **Convention Order** here: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions

David

Comment: Is this answer valid for EF Core as well as old EF?

Comment: Yes it is valid for EF Core too.

Comment: I am not using custom conventions and ef core is appending '1' to one of my model properties and breaking on insert. The cause is the ordering of my modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration in the OnModelCreating(). If I leave the order as the codebase has grown its fine, but as soon as I ordered them alphabetically there was the issue.

Comment: That should be a new question.